# Validating opening hours format

Tags: ruby, google-maps, openstreetmap

I need to validate from my Ruby app the format of the `openingHours` field used by `Open Street Map`. 
I found this validator http://openingh.openstreetmap.de/evaluation_tool/ but I was wondering if there was a gem, REST API or at least a known regex to validate the format expected by them.

This is an example of the opening hours format:

`Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa 10:00-18:00 Su 12:00-17:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example from your question is wrong, a semicolon is missing. The correct format is:

`Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa 10:00-18:00; Su 12:00-17:00`

or in short:

`Mo-Sa 10:00-18:00; Su 12:00-17:00`.

I don't think a regex can handle this complex [format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours/specification). You will need a real parser. The OSM wiki lists several implementations:

- [Key:opening_hours#Implementation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours#Implementation)
- [Key:opening_hours#Code](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours#Code)